# Scale down entire bootstrap page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I zoom down to 80% percent in chrome my bootstrap page looks good.

Is there a way to modify the css to scale down the entire site?

Comment: Are you sure your `width` on all elements is set correctly? Sounds like some parts are wider than the actual monitor resolution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is good practice, but you could try:

```
body {
  transform: scale(0.8); /* 80% */
}
```

Comment: I would recommend tucking that inside of media queries so you only end up scaling for desktop, where users are most likely to have large, high-resolution monitors, and not for something like a phone, where users are likely to be left squinting.

Comment: Indeed, but that is up to the OP since the question was `Is there a way to modify the css to scale down the entire site?`

Comment: This isn't addressing the real issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as I had had the exact same thought as the OP. The problem with the `transform: scale` answer is that it completely breaks the [layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/dashboard/) I'm using.

This barely seems worth posting as an answer, but in my case, I found the majority of style changes from zooming out were from the font itself shrinking.

Using `<body style="font-size: small;">` was quite literally all I needed to replicate that ~80% zoom look.